# Is it possible to improve keyboard + mouse controls?

Tags: pc, senran-kagura-shinovi-versus

While the PC port for Senran Kagura: Shinovi Versus offers both smooth FPS and good textures, it kinda fails when it comes to keyboard + mouse controls. Key rebindings only take effect during a mission, the mouse can't be used to control the camera, and both default and changed keybindings become active during the dialogue between two battles of longer missions. Is there a way (configuration file, mod, any other option) to alleviate the keyboard + mouse issues that the game has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to improve the mouse & keyboard controls yet.